# Subsets of $\Bbb{Z}$ such that $\#((A + 1) \cap B) = \infty$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can we find an **infinite** class of subsets of $\Bbb{Z}$ such that for all $A,B \in $ the class, $\#((A + 1) \cap B) = \infty$ and $\Bbb{Z} = $ the union of all members in the class?

This seems impossibly hard to solve, just putting it out there.

Comment: Assuming $A+1$ means $\{a+1\mid a\in A\}$, a trivial solution is $\{\Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: @David obviously I want an interesting example.

Comment: It is impossible for others to know what **you** mean by "interesting".  Please add more information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$S_m=\{k\in{\Bbb Z}\mid k\ge m\}\ ,$$
then $\{S_m\mid m\in\Bbb Z\}$ is an infinite class that does what you want.